# fastcgi-mono-server4 hangs up

Tags: nginx, mono, debian, fastcgi-mono-server

I have a C# API which I need to have for an C# application.
The problem is, when I start the monoserve process and manualy enter the page, the monoserve process hangs up.

Screenshot: [image: Screenshot]

Monoserve Logfile: http://pastebin.com/raw/3aAdjS10

How I start fastcgi-mono-server4: http://pastebin.com/UctDWu23

Nginx vhost config: http://pastebin.com/raw/fjrvDmca

Nginx Error Log: http://pastebin.com/raw/jBsTEawS

```
fastcgi-mono-server4 --version
Mono.WebServer2.dll 0.4.0.0
(c) (c) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc.
Classes for embedding an ASP.NET server in your application .NET 4.0.
```

```
mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.3 (Stable 4.2.3.4/832de4b Wed Mar 16 13:19:08     UTC 2016)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-    project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported
```

Comment: what distro is this and how did you install mono?

Comment: Version: Debian 8 Jessie (Linux version 3.14.32) :: apt-get install mono-complete :: apt-get install mono-fastcgi-server4

Comment: Did you try to use fastcgi-server from the git repository? (Don't know if they updated the fastcgi server recently, but it used to be *really* outdated)

Comment: compiled from here: https://github.com/mono/xsp/tree/master  no success, same results. Also I think it is the same version as in apt-get repo. Logfile while compiling: http://pastebin.com/raw/MQzNd6W9